# Making a generic array return an array of the same type as the parameter it's passed

Tags: java, generics

So I'm wondering how to create a generic method that, when passed an array of a given type, will return an array of that same type. The code I'm working with currently looks like this:

```
public class InsertionSort<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Sort<T>
{
 public T[] sort (T[] data)
 {
  for (int index = 1; index < data.length; index++)
  {
     T key = data[index];
     int position = index;

     /* Shift larger values to the right */
     while (position > 0 && data[position-1].compareTo(key) > 0)
     {
        data[position] = data[position-1];
        position--;
     }

     data[position] = key;
  }

  return data;
 }
}
```

The problem: when I pass, say, an Integer[] array onto this method as a parameter, it returns data as a basic Comparable[] or Object[] array rather than an Integer[]. Is there a way to change it so so that, if it gets passed an Integer[] array, it sorts it and returns an array of Integer[], but if it gets passed a String[] array, it sorts it and returns an array of String[]? (and so on for any other type that implements Comparable)

Comment: What do you mean by 'it resturns data as a basic Comparable[] or Object[] array'? See http://ideone.com/3gKn4G. It compiles perfectly.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. This code consistently returns the type that I passed it. How are you instantiating the class and calling the sort method?

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, a Java method cannot return more than one type. You can return a generic type, Object, and type cast it in your calling function.

Comment: Ah, cast it in the calling function! Of course! I keep forgetting about doing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bit awkward to work with, but you can do something like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    public <K extends Comparable<K>> K[] getMe(K[] obj) {
        return obj;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();

        Integer[] b = {1,2,3};

        Integer[] d = c.getMe(b);

        for(Integer i : d) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```